# Using R functionalities in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a R function in python:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage
import rpy2.robjects as ro


string = """
cc <- function(x,y) {
xx <- unlist(x, recursive=FALSE)
yy <- unlist(y, recursive=FALSE)
ccf(xx, yy, plot = TRUE)
}
"""

powerpack = SignatureTranslatedAnonymousPackage(string, "powerpack")

x = list(df1["count"].values)
y = list(df2["count"].values)

x = ro.Vector(x)
y = ro.Vector(y)

print (powerpack.cc(x,y))
```

The code is working fine. But the function CCF displays a plot, which I am not able to see or retrieve.

When I run the code a new pop-up window opens but still I am not able to get the plot. Any workarounds?

Comment: Please set up a reproducible example as several sections here cannot run by themselves. For instance, what library is `ccf`? Also, R plots can only display interactively within R sessions using `graphics/grDevices` (built-in graphics libraries), not available in Python. Try saving images to disk. Then view them from file.